# Setting the Dataprovider of a Flex Tree

Tags: apache-flex

```
public function fileBrowse():void {
          var success:Boolean = fileRef.browse();
         }  

         public function initFileAndImageReferences():void {

         fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileRef_select);

        }

        private function fileRef_select(event:Event):void {
            var XMLDP:XML = new XML();
            tree.dataprovider = 

        }
```

After i select a XML file, i need the xml file to be the dataprovider of a Flex tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tree.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(XMLList(XMLDP));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a local file directly in a Flex app. You have to upload it to the server and load the contents from there. This code will upload it to the server.

```
var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
file.upload(uploadURL);
```